# Does spring-data-jdbc consider providing annotations like JPA ID generators?

Tags: spring-data-jdbc

Does spring-data-jdbc consider providing annotations like JPA ID generators? The current way of using events needs to be defined too much, or you need to inherit the base class to implement. Or the current version already provides similar features, but I did not find it? ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there will be Id generators.

No there aren't any yet.

Will they use annotations?
I won't be sure before I implemented it but probably.

Comment: This does not conflict with domain-driven design.  The efficiency is greatly improved, and the ID design of the overall architecture should be logically consistent and more concise and efficient through annotation.